# Is there any way to hotkey Active abilities on items?

Tags: league-of-legends

Some items, such as `Zhonya's Hourglass`, have an Active ability rather than a Passive one, requiring you to click on the item to use the ability. Some of them require rather split second timing, the hourglass in particular, whose ability is `Places your champion into Stasis for 2 seconds, rendering you invulnerable and untargetable but unable to take any actions. 90 second cooldown.`

I know you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for various hotkey shortcuts, but I was wondering if there was any shortcut for item usage (maybe <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1-6</kbd> or something?) that I'm missing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Each item slot, 1-6, is initially bound to the corresponding number key.

You can rebind this during gameplay if you wish, but I like to simply move activated items into the 2nd slot and hit <kbd>2</kbd>.

Comment: I had no idea you could rearrange the item order. Thanks!

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Do note you can't rearrange items from the shop view, only from the inventory on the bottom left.

Comment: When rebinding, you can setup extra mouse buttons not normally used.  I have a "back" button on my mouse by my thumb, and set it to cast whatever's in inventory 6.  Works like a charm.

Comment: I just open my mouse program, bind my middle and thumb buttons to the numbers I use for activating items. I use 4,5 and 6, Less ordering in game as my active items are usually there after I've built them.

Answer (score 4):

It has always been possible to cast item y using the number of item slot. Furthermore the patch note [V1.0.0.125](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.125) added :

> You can now Smart Cast items (you have to manually bind the hotkeys).